# Intellij + Maven + JavaFX: Missing runtime components

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I know that there are various ways of setting up JavaFX with IntelliJ:

- Create JavaFX project in IntelliJ
- New -> Project -> Maven -> create from archtype (see [documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven))
- ...

My approach (for learning purposes):

1. Created new Maven Project (no archtype) with IntelliJ
2. Went to https://mvnrepository.com and searched for [javafx-controls](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/19-ea+3)
3. Added the belonging [central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central) to the pom.xml:

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repo2</id>
            <name>Central Repository from MVNRepository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

4. Copied the dependency from [javafx-controls](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/19-ea+3) into pom.xml

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>19-ea+3</version>
</dependency>
```

5. Now compiling is possible. Maybe one has to restart IntelliJ: File -> Restart IDE...
6. Trying to run the application results in **error "missing javafx runtime components"**

I can see that all jar-files have been downloaded to ".m2\repository\org\openjfx<subolders>".

**Question:** Which step is missing here?

I found similar questions so maybe this one gets rated as "duplicate". However, I think the details differ.

Comment: It looks like not all needed JavaFX libraries are present in the classpath. Check  check the **Run HelloWorld via Maven** section in the JavaFX tutorial page and double check that all the needed JavaFX dependencies are present including the JavaFx maven plugin.

Comment: Just follow Intellij’s instructions on [how to create a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).